# How to access an HTML element that is dynamically filled with values?

Tags: javascript, html, database

I've read lots of stackoverflow questions with no luck. My problem is, I have an HTML page in which I have

```
<select id="myid"></select>
```

and there, there's a Firebase command that retrieves names of values i need, and put it inside the `<option>` like HERE:

```
reference.on("child_added", function (childSnapshot){
  var key = childSnapshot.key;
  var opt = document.createElement('option');
  opt.textContent = key;
  document.getElementById('myid').appendChild(opt);
});
```

Now, i need to somehow access these values, that by the way are correctly appearing in both HTML and my site, however:

```
var val = document.getElementById('myid').value;
console.log(val);
```

It always returns blank in console. I don't know how else can I access it. Whenever I type those values in `<option>` by myself in HTML, everything works as it should and console returns the names that are in database.

@edit: as far as i tried to crack it, it seems to do with the fact that javascript cannot access elements, that for javascript itself aren't yet loaded, but i tried doing window.onload and other similar ones and they don't help.

Comment: when are you calling this `document.getElementById('myid').value;`

Comment: I'm calling it after all the lines that are supposed to fill my <option> elements, so it ,,should'' be visible for it, or am i wrong

Comment: `document.getElementById('myid').value;` will return a result after an option is selected

Comment: This is very true, and I don't know how i missed it. Thank you very much, and sorry for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AngularJS, with directive $scope.watch, i will write a simple example of how to use and the link of documentation, if you have any question talk back to me!

```
function MyController($scope) {

  $scope.myVar = 1;

  $scope.$watch('myVar', function() {
      alert('hey, myVar has changed!');
  });

  $scope.buttonClicked = function() {
      $scope.myVar = 2; // This will trigger $watch expression to kick in
  };
}
```

[AngularJS Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

I hope help with this :)

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Angular.

Comment: @jhpratt It doesn't. But any two way binding framework would solve the problem, and other related problems.